# Buildroot: Unknown own user

Tags: users, buildroot

I crated an image with buildroot. Everything went smooth. When I untarred the bz2 image in vmware and tried to boot into it then I observed an issue, in which, system is unable to recognize any user, even root.

While starting dbus, it gives error as:

`Could not get password database information for UID of current process: User "???" unknown or no memory to allocate password entry`

Unknown username "root" in message bus configuration file

`Could not get password database information for UID of current process: User "???" unknown or no memory to allocate password entry`

`free -m` returns 
total=> 1006 used=> 46 free=> 959

Comment: How exactly did you create that image? Post your config file and the exact commands you ran. Also tell us what files are included in the resulting image. It looks like you're missing `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: I ran the command as: `make menuconfig` `make`. I used the resultant tar.bz2 file to extract in to vmware HD. Kernel cmdline as is `linux /boot/bzImage root=/dev/sda1 init`     Config file is pasted here: http://pastebin.com/2i1iJFkL